# Delete one element out of two without creating a copie of the origianl list JAVA

Tags: java

How to browse a Java list by deleting one item out of two at the same time without creating a copy of the original list.
I tried with this code but I get an empty list in the end. Anyone have an idea?

```
**package test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
public class suppressionUnElementSurDeuxSansCopie {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        
        System.out.println(list);
        
        supprimeElement(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    public static void supprimeElement(List<Integer> list) {
        
        Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();
        
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Integer e = i.next();
            if (list.indexOf(e)%2 ==0) {
                i.remove();
            }
            
            //list.removeIf(n -> (list.indexOf(e)%2==0));
            }
            
        }
    }**
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove every other element, or is there a logic to which elements should be removed?

Comment: I want to remove the elements for example with an even index but without creating a copie of the original list

Comment: When an element is even you remove it. Now the index of the next element used to be three, but is now two because you deleted the previous second element. So your program will keep deleting elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an iterator was the right idea. The problem is that you then use the value from the iterator to refer to the already modified list, which leads to the wrong behavior.

One approach could be to hold a `boolean` indicating if the element is even or not, and flip it as you go:

```
public static void supprimeElement(List<Integer> list) {
    boolean isEven = true;
    Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();
    
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        i.next();
        if (isEven) {
            i.remove();
        }
        isEven = !isEven;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use a stream in this situation.

Comment: No. A Stream does not modify the underlying collection. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: @rady not with this solution, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way I can think of, which is to directly involve the indexes, as that's what you want to use as your criteria for deletion. The trick is to work from back to front so you don't think about how deletions are affecting later candidates:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class suppressionUnElementSurDeuxSansCopie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);

        System.out.println(list);

        supprimeElement(list);

        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static void supprimeElement(List<Integer> list) {
        for (int i = list.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 4]
```

Comment: thank u for your answer. It worked but only when the list contains sorted integers. My question was genaral. what if the list contains strings or other Objects.